# React JS doesn't re-renders map upon state mutation

Tags: reactjs, list, render

I'm currently learning to develop SPA with React and ran into some problems.
My application has currently two components: The first one is called *"NavBarHeader"* and represents a navigation bar which contains three items. Each item inside this navigation is called *"NavBarHeaderItem"* and is represented by an individual component. Initally the item "Data" is selected and references the css
selector "navbar-item-active" to display the currently selected item by using a different background-color. This is accomplished by rendering a list before the render() function returns its elements. Ideally each item should message its parent (the NavBarHeader) if it was selected by the user. However, everytime the 
NavBarHeader updates the selected item, nothing changes eventhough the state was correctly changed by React.

**NavBarHeader.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './NavBarHeader.css';
import NavBarHeaderItem from './NavBarHeaderItem.js';
import folder from './res/folder.svg';
import manager from './res/agenda.svg';
import encyclopedia from './res/encyclopedia.svg'

class NavBarHeader extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.setSelectedItem = this.setSelectedItem.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          selectedItem: "Data",
          // Descriptors contains a text description and an image
          descriptors:[{text:"Data",image:folder},{text:"Tags",image:manager},{text:"Encyclopedia",image:encyclopedia}]
    };
    }

    setSelectedItem(updatedItem)
    {
        // Change the selected item of the NavBar
        this.setState({selectedItem:updatedItem});
    }

    render()
    {
      //Map descriptors to the NavBarHeaderItems
      var currentDescriptors = this.state.descriptors
      var currentlySelectedItem = this.state.selectedItem;
      console.log("["+currentDescriptors+","+currentlySelectedItem+"]");
      var NavBarItems = currentDescriptors.map((descriptor) =>
        <NavBarHeaderItem key={this.state.descriptors.indexOf(descriptor)} 
                      text={descriptor.text} image={descriptor.image} 
                  selected={(currentlySelectedItem === descriptor.text) ? true : false}
              onSelect={this.setSelectedItem}
              />);
        return (
          <ul className ="navbar-header">
                  {NavBarItems}
          </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default NavBarHeader;
```

**NavBarHeaderItem.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './NavBarHeader.css';

    class NavBarHeaderItem extends Component
    {
      constructor(props)
      {
        super(props);
        // Each NavBarHeaderItem has an icon and a descriptive text
        this.state = {
          text: props.text,
          image: props.image,
          selected: this.props.selected,
        };
        // Bind methods to the Component
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
      }

      handleClick()
      {
          console.log("Click!");
          this.props.onSelect(this.state.text);
      }

      render()
      {
        console.log("["+this.state.text+","+this.state.selected+"]");
        // Normal item which will be rendered if
        const normalItem = (
          <li className="navbar-item" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img className="navbar-item-image" src={this.state.image} alt=""/>
            <a className="navbar-item-text">{this.state.text}</a>
          </li>
        );
        // Selected items have a different appearance
        const selectedItem=(
          <li className="navbar-item-active" onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <img className="navbar-item-image" src={this.state.image} alt=""/>
            <a className="navbar-item-text">{this.state.text}</a>
          </li>
        );
        if(this.state.selected)
        {
          return (
            selectedItem
          )
        } else if(!this.state.selected)
        {
          return (
            normalItem
          )
        }
      }
    }

    export default NavBarHeaderItem;
```

Comment: Please include the source for `NavBarHeaderItem` too.

Answer (score 0):

In the `NavBarHeaderItem` constructor you are copying all props into state and then using the state in `render()`, but the constructor will only be invoked once - not on each render of `NavBarHeaderItem`. This means that the state will remain unchanged over the lifetime of the component and that explains the behaviour you are seeing.

You should change `NavBarHeaderItem.render()` to use data from `props` instead of `state` - change all instances of `this.state.selected` to `this.props.selected`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Everything is working as intended now